# Matching a string between two sets of characters without using lookarounds

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I've been working on some regex to try and match an entire string between two characters. I am trying to capture everything from "System", all the way down to "prod_rx." (I am looking to include both of these strings in my match). Below is the full text that I am working with:

`\"alert_id\":\"123456\",\"severity\":\"medium\",\"summary\":\"System generated a Medium severity alert\\\\prod_rx.\",\"title\":\"123456-test_alert\",`

The regex that I am using right now is...:

`(?<=summary\\":\\").*?(?=\\")`

This works perfectly when I am able to use lookarounds, such as in Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/jXltNZ/1. However, the regex parser in the software that my company uses does not support lookarounds (crazy, right?).

Anyway - my question is basically how can I match the above text described without using lookaheads/lookbehinds. Any help is VERY MUCH appreciated!!

Comment: Use `summary\\":\\"(.*?)\\"`, see https://regex101.com/r/jXltNZ/2. Grab Group 1 value.

Comment: When you can't use lookarounds, put a capture group around the part that you want to match, and then extract that group from the result.

Comment: Are you still struggling with this or is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we can simply use other non-lookaround method, such as this simple expression:

```
.+summary\\":\\"(.+)\\",
```

and our data is in this capturing group:

```
(.+)
```

our right boundary is:

```
\\",
```

and our left boundary is:

```
.+summary\\":\\"
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0J2Z3/1)